# Understanding Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for expectation of outer products of random vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23545267_A_Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality_for_expectation_of_matrices) (lemma 1), which states that

> for random vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{q}$ such that $\mathbb{E}\|x\|^2_2<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}\|y\|^2_2<\infty$, and $\mathbb{E}[yy^\top]$ is invertible,
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbb{E}[xx^\top]-\mathbb{E}[xy^\top]\mathbb{E}[yy^\top]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[yx^\top]
> \end{align*}
> is positive semidefinite.

Is it true that the maximum set of eigenvalues of $\mathbb{E}[xy^\top]\mathbb{E}[yy^\top]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[yx^\top]$ is achieved when $y=x$.

If not, then what can we say about how the eigenvalues of $\mathbb{E}[xx^\top]$ compare with those of $\mathbb{E}[xy^\top]\mathbb{E}[yy^\top]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[yx^\top]$? Thanks.

Comment: The author cites a paper by G. Tripathi. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Yup, it doesn't say anything about eigenvalues.

Comment: By $B$, did you mean $y$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've edited it.